# Determinant of a special type of skew symmetric matrix with complex entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $a_1,...,a_{2n} \in \mathbb C$ and $A=[b_{ij}]\in M(2n,\mathbb C)$ such that $A^T=-A$ and $b_{ij}=a_ia_j,\forall i<j$.

Can we find a nice expression for determinant of $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, $A=DKD$ where $D=\operatorname{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_{2n})$ and $K$ is the skew symmetric matrix whose strictly upper triangular part is one. It is easy to prove that $\det(K)=1$. Hence $\det(A)=\prod_{i=1}^{2n}a_i^2$.

Comment: could you please elaborate how did you get that $A=DKD$ with $D,K$ as described?

Comment: okay I think I can see how $A=DKD$ ... but why $\det (K)=1$ ?

Comment: @user521337 There are lots of ways to prove that. Row operations, Sylvester determinant theorem, Schur complement etc..